# Regex Expression for words between two punctuation

Tags: php, regex

How can I make this regex expression find every string in my text that matches this format, I tried adding the curly braces but it only find the first word in the format and when removed it find every word.

```
My regex expression: {((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))
My text: {Hello|Hi|Hey} John, How are you? I'm fine
```

Comment: Can you precisely list what are your expected matches? Is it individual matches `Hello` `Hi` `Hey`?

Comment: How can I only get individual matches of the words between the punctuations liek Hello Hi Hey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the matches between curly brackets, you could match from `{` till `}` and capture what is in between in a capturing group.

Then use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and use `|` as a delimiter. If you have multiple results you could loop the results:

```
$str = "My text: {Hello|Hi|Hey} John, How are you? I'm fine";
preg_match_all('~{([^}]+)}~', $str, $matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
    print_r(explode('|', $match));
}
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => Hi
    [2] => Hey
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/jCB0R)

Another option could be to make use of the `\G` anchor:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|{(?=[^{}]*?}))([^|{}]+)[|}]
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\G(?!\A)` End of the previous match but not at the start
  - `|` Or
  - `{(?=[^{}]*?})` Match `{` and assert what follows contains not `}` and then `}`
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `([^|{}]+)` Capture in a group matching NOT what is listed in the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- `[|}]` Match what is listed in the character class

[php demo](https://3v4l.org/ERkAp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this look around based regex that will give you all the matches in curly brackets,

```
(?<=[{|])\w+(?=[|}])
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lz61Md/1)**

Try this Python code,

```
$s = "{Hello|Hi|Hey} John, How are you? I'm fine";
preg_match_all('/(?<=[{|])\w+(?=[|}])/',$s,$matches);
print_r($matches);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hello
            [1] => Hi
            [2] => Hey
        )

)
```

**[Online PHP demo](https://rextester.com/YPRNSU43263)**